# VBA. Array for search or replace

Tags: arrays, vba

Need to found any symbol of array.

For example: 
replace(string,[a,b,c,e,f,g],"a1b2c3d4e567");
result = "1234567"

How do it ?

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is to remove all non-numeric characters, the following will work:

```
' Added reference for Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5

Const s As String = "a1b2c3d4e567"
Dim regex2 As New RegExp
Dim a As String

regex2.Global = True
regex2.Pattern = "[^0-9]"
Dim a As String = regex2.Replace(s, "")

MsgBox (a)   ' Outputs 1234567
```

If you are looking for specific characters, change the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you are going to have to do this by consecutive calls to replace

```
result = "a1b2c3d4e567"
result = replace(result,"a","")
result = replace(result,"b","")
result = replace(result,"c","")
```

etc